# Using loop values for range to set values

Tags: google-apps-script

So i have a complexed Google Sheet which i am using to track calendar events and i need a loop to run in order for it then populate the relevant cell with its values. The Sheet name and relevant range are pre calculated in the google sheet so the loop pulls that data and then needs to use it to set the range value from the loop with its value. Now it pulls the sheet name no problem but kicks up an error for the range stating that it is not a valid range (i know it is as if i add it in manually as 3,17,1,1 it populates the correct cell on the loop value sheetname.

So any ideas what i can do to get the range value to work from the loop?

```js
function UpdateUsersTracker(){
  //calendardetails();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Calendar Events');      
  var vals = sheet.getRange("B14:B").getValues();
  var last = vals.filter(String).length +13;       
  var events = sheet.getRange('B14:T' + last).getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) 
        { 
        if(events[i][13] != "Full")             
        {ss.getSheetByName(events[i][17]).getRange(events[i][13]).setValue('HH')};
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is somewhere in the `last` variable. What value does it have? You can use `Logger.log()` to find that out. That `String` there is weird as well.

Comment: the var `last` shouldn't be an issue, that is just there to get the last row number that has data in it to determine the range size for the var `events`

Comment: But it's an unusual way to get the last row. Why don't you use the builtin `getLastRow()` method? Try using `var last = sheet.getLastRow()` instead of what you currently have.

Comment: it returns the same value and still fails on the final getRange().setValue() due to Range Not Found. the Log for the range value from the sheet returns it correctly for the first instance as 3,17,1,1. I tend not to use getLastRow as you cant do it against just 1 column, alot of what i do can have varying lengths of columns so getLastRow is not sufficient

Comment: Ok then, the problem might be in the spreadsheet. The thing is, if it says `Range Not Found`, the range is not found so whatever is passed to the `getRange()` method - is incorrect. You can either debug it yourself using the `Logger`, or you can make a copy of the spreadsheet and let us check what's going wrong.

Comment: sorry, just to be 100% clear the issue is with this line `{ss.getSheetByName(events[i][17]).getRange(events[i][13]).setValue('HH')};` and in particular this bit `getRange(events[i][13])`

Comment: for this to work, `events[i][13]` must be a valid A1Annotation range (string like `'B1:C12'` for example).

Comment: ok, i can convert it in the sheet to show as A1:B1 no problem. But why would it need to be a valid A1Annotation range? why wouldn't row, column, no.rows, no.cols not work?

Comment: Due to how `getRange()` works. It either takes an A1Annotation range, or a `row, column, no.rows, no.cols` list of params. When you call it like this `getRange(events[i][13])` it has only one parameter, so it needs to be A1Annotation string.

Comment: ok, great. I will change it over to pull through A1Annotation then and see if that works, thanks.

Comment: Adelin - LEGEND!!! All works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered correctly by Adelin, getRange would not accept reange type like getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns), only works for getRange(a1Notation)

Comment: Actually it accepts both, as I've stated in the comments, but **if you use only one parameter, it must be an A1Annotation**. Nevertheless, glad you've found the solution.